# Could anyone correct this PAM(Partitioning Around Medoids) algorithm which I know

Tags: clustering

Hi I'm quite confused about Partitioning Around Medoids.

Firstly, When the centre objects are swapped, how many objects are supposed to be swapped?
For example, if there are 4 medoids, then do all of them need to be changed? or just one? or does it depend on analyst?

Secondly, there were 4 medoids A,B,C,D and D is swapped with E.
However, what if A,B,D,E were best objects in forming clusters?
I know once object is replaced, the object never come back. Or should I take this thing as a drawback of PAM?

Thank you so much!!!!! Have a amazing day :)

Comment: Or, does every pairs of medoids and non-medoids are considered? Like When I considered to swap D with E, I need to considered to swap A with E, B with E, C with E as well??

Answer (score 0):

The *best* single swap is executed.

Then, a new best swap is found - this *may* involve an earlier medoid (it's just not likely to happen - in your example, this would mean the first swap was not optimal).

When there is no swap that further improves the result. PAM finishes.